# iOS doesn't propose Strong Password modal React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I'm unable to show the modal use a strong password on iOS, I have tried everything.

I have tried using oneTimeCode it doesn't work, I have tried `blurOnSubmit={false}` `onSubmitEditing={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}` it doesn't work either. I have added the associated domain in XCODE and it still doesn't work.

I'm running it on iPhone, but the same happens in the simulator.

I'm using iOS 16. Expo 46.0.16, react-native 0.69.6

I have an autofill password turned on and I have keychain enabled in iCloud.

```
        <TextInput
            style={{
              borderColor: 'red',
              borderWidth: 1,
              height: 80,
              width: '100%',
            }}
            textContentType="username"
            value={val}
            onChangeText={text => setVal(text)}
            autoCorrect={false}
            placeholder="Password"
          />
          <TextInput
            style={{
              borderColor: 'red',
              borderWidth: 1,
              height: 80,
              width: '100%',
            }}
            blurOnSubmit={false}
            onSubmitEditing={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}
            passwordRules="required: upper; required: lower; required: digit; max-consecutive: 2; minlength: 8;"
            value={value}
            onChangeText={text => setValue(text)}
            autoCorrect={false}
            placeholder="Password"
            secureTextEntry
            textContentType="newPassword"
          />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve it by adding the `associated domains` in XCode.

[image: assosietated domains]

Remember that the domain must be valid and it should have a valid SSL certificate.

You will then need to add to your web server, the associated domain file.

This is the most basic example for it to work. You can check the whole example and more on the associated domains here [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains)

### JSON FILE

```js
{
    "webcredentials": {
      "apps": [ "MFSDSD3F.com.bundle.identify" ]
  }
}
```

---

The string in the apps array is as follows:

```
MFSDSD3F = TeamID - which you can find on your [developer account][3] under Membership details.
```

```
com.bundle.identify = Your Bundle Identifier.
```

---

## Hosting

You must host the file using https:// with a valid certificate and with no redirects.

### File URL

```
https://<fully qualified domain>/.well-known/apple-app-site-association
```